# Method of Successive Approximations With Arbitrary Continuous Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that Picard's method of successive approximation (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Successive_Approximations) works if we start with an arbitrary continuous function such that $y(x_0)=y_0$.

In class we proved that if we use the method of successive approximation starting with the constant function $y=y_0$ then it converges to the unique answer to the IVP $Dy=f(x,y)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$. My "proof" appeals to the fact that any continuous curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is homeomorphic to the constant function, thus we can construct a unique integral curve in that space and apply the inverse of the homeomorphism. But this is just a bunch of handwaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But this is just a bunch of handwaving". Actually it is a bit worse, your argument cannot be turned into a proof (I will omit the technical complications).

You really need to make the computations, as in the case of a constant function. The good part is that these are almost the same in the general case. Simply look at the link to wikipedia that you included, specifically at the line starting with $|y_n(x)-y_{n-1}(x)|$ and replace $y_{n-1}$ by your "initial" function.

Comment: I guess what it all boils down to is that the method of successive approximations is just the repeated application of a contraction on continuous functions that spits out other continuous functions, so you get a fixed point by Banach's theorem, and then you just show that your fixed point solves the IVP.